# Test to force a race condition using CowntDownLatch causes java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, countdownlatch

I tried to create a test where I tried to force a race condition (or at least to increase the probability of its occurrence) and I've used a `CountDownLatch`.

The problem is that I get a `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` at my `CountDownLatch.wait()`. I'm certainly misusing the `CountDownLatch` and I'm surely not creating this test in a clever way.

This simple code reproduces my idea and my problem (I also have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/rmsam/8058e11e43e194f55572)):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Example {

    private static BusinessLogic logic;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Integer NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS = 10;
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS);
        logic = new BusinessLogic();

        // trying to force the race condition
        List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS);
        for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS; i++) {
            Thread worker = new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(latch));
            threads.add(worker);
            worker.start();
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_OF_PARALLEL_THREADS; i++) {
            try {
                threads.get(i).wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Just a dummy business logic class.
     * I want to "force" a race condition at the method doSomething().
     */
    private static class BusinessLogic {
        public void doSomething() {
            System.out.println("Doing something...");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Worker runnable to use in a Thead
     */
    private static class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {
        private CountDownLatch latch;

        private WorkerRunnable(CountDownLatch latch) {
            this.latch = latch;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                // 1st I want to decrement the latch
                latch.countDown();
                // then I want to wait for every other thread to 
                latch.wait(); // the exception is thrown in this line.
                // hopefully increase the probability of a race condition...
                logic.doSomething();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The javadoc of the `CountDownLatch.wait()` states that the `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown if the current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor. But I'm afraid I'm not understanding what this mean, nor I am able to figure how could I recreate my code to avoid this exception.

EDIT: with the tips provided in the answers, I've created a new version of the example above and I've stored in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rmsam/c6ed4a5c83b237dc4678). I don't have any exceptions now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [`await()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await()), not [`wait()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()).

`await()` will wait until the latch reaches zero.  `wait()` is unrelated to latches, and is not what you want in your `WorkerRunnable`.  But FYI, in order to call `wait()` without getting an exception, you have to own an object's monitor, and to become the owner, you have to be in a block that's `synchronized` on that object.

Comment: Ouch :/ ! That was exactly the problem that caused the exception: using wait() when I really wanted await(). Silly me...

Comment: `.await()` did it for me too. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

Your controller thread (usually the main/ui thread) should do the waiting, while the worker threads do the countdown-ing.

You should start the threads from your main thread and insert the `latch.await()` call there - right after you've started them.
Each worker thread should call `latch.countdown()` upon completion.

When allthreads have called `countdown()` the CountDownLatch will exit `latch.await()`in the main thread and transfer the control of execution to it (the code after `latch.await()` will start executing).

So basically you need to move the `await()` to the main program right after you've started the worker threads.

EDIT: You should also remove the `Thread.wait()` calls because that is another multithreading framework - wait/notify and it is much more low-level than using a CountDownLatch (Unless you need it for your simulation. I don't quite understand your test case)

Comment: Thanks for your tips! :) I want every thread to block before they call the business logic method so that they all execute it "at the same time". If I move the await() to the main thread, I won't have any means of blocking the threads before calling BusinessLogic.doSomething().

Comment: You should move the await there, because a single thread cannot call countdown and await. You could make those threads block by calling Thread.wait(), instead of latch.await()

Comment: Hm, I see. So, even tough I was able to create a version of the sample code from the question without exceptions (see my edit) I might not be achieving the result I hope?

Answer (score 0):

When trying to call `wait()` an any object you'll have to have the monitor of that object.

```
Object o = new Object();
o.wait();
```

will cause an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

You have to synchronize on that object in order to be able to call `wait()`:

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized(o) {
    o.wait();
}
```